# Purescript: drawing an image on a canvas

Tags: purescript

I'd like to use Purescript to draw an image to a canvas. When I did this in Javascript, it looked something like the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");  // THIS LINE IN PURESCRIPT???
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};
```

I'm using purs 0.12. I have installed Graphics.Canvas and I can use it to draw rectangles and ellipses and such. But I can't figure out the API to `drawImage`. I also can't figure out in what library the Purescript equivalent of `getElementbyId()` resides.

Comment: It seems that `drawImage` is available [in the same library](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-canvas/4.0.0/docs/Graphics.Canvas#v:drawImage). Are you having some specific problems with it?

Comment: It takes a `CanvasImageSource` -- so the question is where do I get that?

Comment: It seems that can be obtained via [tryLoadImage](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-canvas/4.0.0/docs/Graphics.Canvas#v:tryLoadImage)

Comment: I can't make any sense of the arguments to `tryLoadImage` . In fact, how is that supposed to produce a `CanvasImageSource` . it takes a function with a `Maybe CanvasImageSource` as an argument... huh????

Comment: EDIT: I suppose I could write such a function which incorporates a call to `drawImage` with the context and coordinates as a closure, and one that takes a `Maybe CanvasImageSource` as an argument (I have to handle the `Nothing` case as well),  then pass it to `tryLoadImage` every time I want to draw something, but that doesn't seem like it's what's intended

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org) to search for definitions such as [`getElementById`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=getElementById).

[`tryLoadImage`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-canvas/4.0.0/docs/Graphics.Canvas#v:tryLoadImage) takes a callback as an argument. The callback is what receives the `CanvasImageSource`. You may wish to use [`Aff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/5.1.1) or at least [`ContT`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/4.2.0/docs/Control.Monad.Cont.Trans#t:ContT) to help.